# accessing a random variable from another class

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, private

It maybe a really easy question, but I'm confused. I have a main class and many other classes. In class DATA, one array (X_TRAIN) will be generated randomly.

```
public class DATA {

    public double[][] X_TRAIN;

    public DATA() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

         X_TRAIN = new double[2][2];
// X_TRAIN will be filled randomly
    }

    public double[][] X_TRAIN() {
        return X_TRAIN;
    }
 }
```

the way I call DATA class in other classes is the following:

```
DATA data_input = new DATA();
```

and the problem is that each time I call DATA, a totally new arrays (X_TRAIN) will be generated and it is not what I want. I want to have a unique X_TRAIN array. I need to call DATA because I need to have access to X_TRAIN in other classes. Maybe I'm using a wrong method to have access to X_TRAIN. My code is written in maven and the IDE is netbeans. 
I even tried to define X_TRAIN as private:

```
private double[][] X_TRAIN;
```

and got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - X_TRAIN has private access in com.mycompany.cpxr_main.DATA
at com.mycompany.cpxr_main.MAIN_CLASS.main(MAIN_CLASS.java:61)
```

Comment: What are `two` and `three`? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Thanks a lot for finding my mistake. The original code is different from what I wrote here and It was my mistake to modify the code. The question is updated.

Comment: Your curly braces seem messed up. The class ends before the method or variable

Comment: Do you already know the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)? If no, please take some time and read it.

Comment: Pass your `Data` instances to your other methods. Or make `Data` a `Singleton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have another constructor

```
public DATA(double[][] trains){
  X_TRAIN = trains;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a single instance of `X_TRAIN` you need to define it as *static*. By this, you can generate it once and then access it through `DATA.X_TRAIN`